# Trying to get property 'image_two' of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, postgresql, heroku

I have connected pgadmin to heroku database with their settings.
I Migration is also successful by postres migration tool
But not the app is showing something except errors,Everything was working fine on localhost
successfully deployed.
When I fetch rows data from table it shows no data in postgres pgadmin even after migration

website url: https://agile-stream-57638.herokuapp.com/

error

```
(3/3) ErrorException
Trying to get property 'image_two' of non-object (View: /app/resources/views/layouts/slider.blade.php) (View: /app/resources/views/layouts/slider.blade.php)
```

slider.blade.php

```
    <!-- Banner -->
    @php
        $slider = DB::table('products')
                ->join('brands','products.brand_id','brands.id')
                ->select('products.*','brands.brand_name')
                ->where('main_slider',1)->orderBy('id','DESC')
                ->first();

    @endphp

    <div class="banner">
        <div class="banner_background" style="background-image:url({{ asset('public/frontend/images/banner_background.jpg')}})"></div>
        <div class="container fill_height">
            <div class="row fill_height">
                <div class="banner_product_image"><img src="{{ asset($slider->image_two )}}" alt=""
                    style="height: 300px;"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 offset-lg-4 fill_height">
                    <div class="banner_content">
                        <h1 class="banner_text">{{ $slider->product_name }} </h1>
                        <div class="banner_price">
                            @if($slider->discount_price == Null)
                                <h2>{{ $slider->selling_price }} </h2>
                            @else
                                <span>{{ $slider->selling_price }}</span>{{ $slider->discount_price }}</div>
                            @endif


                        <div class="banner_product_name">{{ $slider->brand_name }}</div>
                        <div class="button banner_button"><a href="#">Shop Now</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please share your `slider.blade.php`?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert i shared it   , Project is working fine on localhost

Comment: I mean, please add the content of your `slider.blade.php` to your question so we can help you

Comment: @ChristopheHubert   that is content click on it

Comment: Please add the code as text so it is easier to read 

Comment: @ChristopheHubert : it is done

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have sliders in your database so your `$slider` is `null`
You need to check first the existence before displaying the first slider:

```
<!-- Banner -->
@if($slider)
    <div class="banner">
        <!-- Your slider here -->
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: there is image_two in database and slider is variable getting fields see it in @php brackets

Comment: try to run `dd($slider);` at the end of your @php bracket, it will return `null` because you don't have result from your query

Comment: it may be that there is no data in database   . But i have successfully done migration, and it is confirm there is no data in database as other login page is also not working

Comment: You are not doing `null` checking in your application, on your localhost you have data so no error is showing. Same thing for your `login`, you are trying to get `phone_one` from an object that doesn't exist.

Comment: If you want to test that locally, run `php artisan migrate:refresh` to rollback then re-run all your migrations

Comment: but with that all my categories and products will go , I have done migrate:refresh , i know it,  i will do all null, checking, but i want to see my project working, i want first stage to be completed

Comment: Well then you have to populate the database with data, the best option for you is to create a Seeder (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/seeding) or copy the database from your local machine to your live app

Comment: ya i have seeding for admin user, but index page has many products that can't be seeded, I have done migration from mysql to postgres on server ,don't know why the data not updated

Comment: Your problem is not anymore related to your question. Please validate the answer and open a new question if necessary 

Comment: Thanks, please accept the answer so it can help others as well 

Comment: i have done it many times but it shows people with less than 15 reputation are counted but not showed   , also the problem is also solved , the database had no data,, i used then other migration tool which worked. Thank You

Comment: to accept the answer, you have to select the checkmark below the voting up-down arrows next to the answer 